# How does Django models interact with non-Django files

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am new to Django and am learning by doing.

My original web app only used `view.py`,`base.html` and a non-Django python file `es.py` to connect to a NoSQL database(Elasticsearch) to search over index B. I do most of the front-end in `base.html`.

The app now need to have some dependent drop down based on fields in index A and then enable search over index B filtered by the selected value. So the values need to be somewhat "global".

A snippet of 
`base.html` for the new selection function

```
<form class="indexA-selection">
 <input list="site">
<datalist id="site">
  <option value="aa">
  <option value="bb">
  <option value="cc">
  <option value="dd">
</datalist>
    <button class="btn" type="submit">Show Result</button>
  </form>
<br>
  <form class="form-inline">

    <input 
    class="form-control mr-sm-2" 
    type="query" placeholder="query" 
    aria-label="query"
    name = 'query'
    value = "">
    <button class="btn" type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>
```

`views.py`

```
def search_index(request):
    results = []
    search_term = ""
    v_site=""
    if request.GET.get('query'):
        search_term = request.GET['query'] #this is the original search
    if request.GET.get('site'):
        v_site = request.GET['site']  
    print(v_site)   #no value gets printed,so I don't think value in html is passed
    allcate=categories(v_site) #function from non-Django py file.
     #If v_site is passed, this will return a nested dictionary for dependent drop-downs 
    print(allcate)
    results = esearch(query=search_term) #function from non-Django py file
    print(results)
    context = {'results': results, 'count': len(results), 'search_term': search_term,'allcate':allcate}
    return render(request, 'esearch/index.html', context)
```

I was trying to create select/drop down but it seems Django does not support them in `.html`. I searched and found it seems that I have to use `models.py`.

I read some examples and can't find how `models.py` interact with non-Django python files.

Is there an example that illustrates this? What's the easiest way to enable the structure for the project? Thanks.

Comment: Could you please post some code of what you have tried so far?

Comment: @NicoGriffioen Updated with the current code that I am stuck with.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're trying to do. Do you want to have allcate as options in the datalist in your html?

Comment: Yes. The beginning selection/drop down only has 4 possible values so I just listed them in html. I planned to have other dependent drop downs created and populated with JavaScript using values in allcate.

Comment: I don't understand what a "non-Django Python file" is. There is no distinction between Django and non-Django Python.

Comment: And I also don't understand why you think Django does not support dropdowns in HTML. Django doesn't at all stop you creating select boxes, not sure why you think it does (or even could).

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks for the input. By non-Django python file I refer to the pythons files that are not automatically generated when creating a Django project. I saw many examples of creating dependent drop down based on db.sqlite3,`models.py` and `forms.py`. I am not sure if I can follow that as for my project,  the database is not connected via `settings.py`.

Comment: But there is no distinction. You can call any Python code.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the context of your view in the HTML template through the `{% %}` and `{{ }}` tags.

See [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/language/](http://the%20Django%20docs)

Change your data list to something like this (Assuming categories have a name and id field):

```
<datalist id="site">
    {% for category in allcate %} 
    <option value="{{category.id}}">
        {{ category.name }}
    </option>
    {% endfor %} 
</datalist>
```

Also consider choosing a more verbose name like all_categories